# Partition External Hard Drive 1.5TB which is on FAT32 format into 3 partitions of 500GB each in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, fat32

I would like to partition a 1.5TB external hard drive which is in FAT32 format into 3 partitions of 500GB each.

Comment: I tried clicking on My Computer > Manage > Disk Management > Right click on the external hard drive, but unable to click on Shrink Volume

Comment: Please don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they're satisfactory (you can always change it if a better one comes up).

Answer (score 2):

If you can put files away, I'd suggest you delete any volumes on your drive from Disk Management, create 3 500GB new partitions and copy files back.

Unless you require FAT32 for compatibility purposes, I'd suggest you create your volumes as NTFS (it will ask you when creating partitions). It is more resilient against file errors, and supports file sizes larger than 4GB.

Once volumes have been deleted, follow this procedure ([more info here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx)):

1. Right-click an unallocated region on your hard disk, and then click
   New Simple Volume.
2. In the New Simple Volume Wizard, click Next.
3. Type the size of the volume you want to create in megabytes (MB, so ~5000000 for 500GB) or accept the maximum default size, and then click Next.
4. Accept the default drive letter or choose a different drive letter
   to identify the partition, and then click Next. (you can always change the letter later)
5. In the Format Partition dialog box, select "quick formatting" and format the drive. Leave the allocation unit size at default, and you can give a label name too. I don't recommended file and folder compression.
6. Repeat for other volumes in the unallocated space.

Comment: there are no files, brand new one

Comment: Good, just delete the volume, and right-click again to create new ones. It will ask you for the size.

Comment: Now there are the below options, which one to choose : New Simple Volume, New Striped Volume, New Spanned Volume, New Mirrored Volume

Comment: @TMN Simple volume, edited my asnwer.

Comment: one quick question, should I use NTFS or eFAT as I am going to use this for recording movies/programs from Free to Air Satellite HD PVR

Comment: @TMN I believe eFAT (exFAT) is more intended for flash card storage and usb keys. Use NTFS.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT